# mongodb: syntax for referring to a collection in commands

Tags: collections, syntax, mongodb

i'm trying to convert a collection to a capped collection, but i'm having trouble getting the syntax right. can someone tell me how to refer to my collection? it's full name is manage.api_requests. here is what i've tried so far:

```
> db.runCommand( { convertToCapped:api_requests, size: 38654705664 } )  
Sat Mar 26 10:29:02 ReferenceError: api_requests is not defined (shell):1
> db.runCommand( { convertToCapped:db.api_requests, size: 38654705664 } )
{
  "errmsg" : "cloneCollectionAsCapped failed: { errmsg: \"exception: source collection manage.manage.api_requests does not exist\", code: 10301, ok: 0.0 }",
  "ok" : 0
}
> db.runCommand( { convertToCapped:manage.api_requests, size: 38654705664 } )
Sat Mar 26 10:42:40 ReferenceError: manage is not defined (shell):1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection name must be quoted of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to pass a string to this command.  If new collection is to be called "api_requests" that pass that - including the "" - otherwise, it's not a string and the shell tries to resolve it as a variable name.